# hr not seen when printing

Tags: html

I'm writing some html to be shown in the screen and sent by e-mail too (I'm making it with tables). I want to sepair the sections. I've tried putting some hr tags and it's seen properly in the navigators (Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox 10) and in the email managers (Outlook 2010, Hotmail and GMail). Well, if I print it (in the navigators) I don't see the hr tags. I have the same problem with a label whose background color is seen in the navigators and email managers but when the document is printed is not seen. (The css file is the same for showing in screen and for printing).

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: After a quick test of some HTML with an <hr>, I can print the document and the <hr> shows in the print. Can you post some code please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The background not printing is a preference setting in your browser. It's off by default to save ink. But if the `hr` (or any construct) is white and is showing on the coloured background on your screen, you might want to switch this setting on.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this. Preference printer settings control this.

Answer (score 33):

You can make an `<hr>` that's printable without changing browser settings like this:

```css
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-top: solid 1px #aaa;
}
```

*caveat: I only tested in chrome.*

Comment: This also works in IE... I like this approach! Thank you

Comment: Asking to print background did not work for me with firefox/xenial combination, but this workaround did. However, I needed to remove `display:block;` in order for the element not to have a black line below the top border.

Comment: in my experience it seems that the only thing that is really required is the black border-top property

Answer (score 10):

Make

---

printable without changing browser settings:

```css
hr {
  border-top: solid 1px #000 !important;
}
```

caveat: Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge.

Comment: This works. However, interestingly, `background-color: black !important;` does only work in the "print" emulation in chrome, not the actual print preview.